# How to follow a post?

Tags: support, answers, notifications

Sometimes when browsing Stack Overflow I come across a (non-answered yet) question to which I would like to get the answer of. 
So, I would like to be informed when answers have been posted (even better, informed when an answer has been accepted), possibly by emails (e.g. same way we get informed when someone answered our own question).

Am I correct that there is no way to do this yet? I looked for such button, but I might have missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the star feature below the reputation counter to track interesting questions. You can find such marked question in your profile under the `favorites` tab.

Comment: Does starring (favoriting) a question cause new answers and comments to it to show up in our SO inbox?

Comment: The star button adds the question to your bookmarks. It does not information you of activity. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291468/how-can-we-follow-everything-about-a-question

Answer (score 4):

You can use the RSS question feed link you'll at the bottom at every question page (perhaps a bit hard to find if not aware of it).

For example, the feed for this page is:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/254268

[image: Snap]

Click on it and most modern browsers will allow you to subscribe to it, or use your favorite RSS feed reader.

It will eventually show up when a new answer becomes available:

[image: Snap2]

Comment: This is certainly a good way to follow your interested question, but seriously subscribe every question you the interested question in your RSS reader? I don't really think that doable which definitely will mass my RSS list :(