# How can we "follow" everything about a question?

Tags: support, questions

Yes. I have read the numerous posts on this subject (including [How to follow a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254268/how-to-follow-a-post) The problem I have with that post is it does not notify me of comments and up/down votes). I want to know if I can be notified of everything about the post (such as new comments, votes, closed, etc) as if I was the OP. Can I do this? Does the RSS feed cover this? The favorite option doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: I thought I had made it clear the differences between the possible duplicates and my question

Comment: Jake, I suppose this means "no" then.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302607/

Answer (score 3):

There is a new "follow" feature available, which can be found after the "share" and "edit" links below any question or answer.

[image]

This will notify you of any activity on a followed question/answer, and anything being followed appears under the "Following" tab in your profile.

[image]

Note that this is different from the favourite button, which just adds a bookmark, shown under the Bookmarks tab of your profile.