# Is it possible to get notifications of question activity without adding a comment or answer?

Tags: support, notifications

I am interested in a particular question and I need to know about activity on the question. Is it possible to get the activity notification? I did not add any comment or answer to the question

I added the question as "Favorite" but still did not get the activity notifications.

Is there a way?

Comment: may be useful as a feature...

Comment: Yeah, it seems like favoriting should be like watching, so you can track changes. I know how to bookmark a page, so it's kind of a redundant feature by itself.

Comment: Maybe add a feature like "Get notifications"? It would be good. Probably it's SE meta question

Comment: there is a rss question feed link, [example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/302607)

Comment: @kelly not entirely, bookmarks go on the heap of existing ones and you need to stall them and probably rename them to have easy access to them. The favorite feature is a more readable and easier to find version of the bookmarks, and also counts as a statistic on the question itself.

Comment: @Jet: Yes; for example, [my own suggestion to help wikify SE more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261069/274165).

Comment: On Quora you can "follow" questions = you'll get notifications but nobody else can see what you're following. Would be useful on SE too, I always just leave a tab open so I wouldn't forget to check it later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [StackEye](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites). It's an awesome [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm?hl=en).

Comment: Anything for Firefox users?

Comment: @HunterStevens The knowledge that it's a superior browser? (sobs)

Comment: Other than that, of course. I am guessing you can use GreaseMonkey or something maybe?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of. The extension's code is [opensource](https://github.com/blunderboy/stackeye), though.

Comment: What good are bookmarks if you have stackeye? I'm only interested in notifications. Are bookmarks any good in that case?

Comment: Is there some workaround to be able to watch more than 20 questions with stackeye?

Answer (score 13):

There is no additional way to get notifications that pop up in the top bar as red-boxed numbers, no. Checking [your favorites tab](//stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites) from time to time is as good as it gets.